# Checking admin roles in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I'm doing my project using Laravel framework. Everything seems to be perfect. However, in my login part, I want to do something like when a user login into the system, it will check the "is_admin" column. If the "is_admin" column is equal to 1, it will go straight to admin page. 
I've been looking on the Internet but I can't find the answer for this. I also did use Middleware but it didn't work. I don't know why. Can somebody help me with this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.1 allows authorization, you can add something like this in your `AuthServiceProvider`

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate){
    $gate->define('admin', function($user){
        return $user->is_admin;
    });
}
```

Then use the `Gate` facade in your controllers like

```
$user=Auth::user();
if(Gate::allows('admin', $user)){
    //user is admin
}
```

Take a look at this part of Laravel's documentation
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in your `AuthController.php`

```
if(Auth::user()->is_admin == 1){
    protected $redirectTo = 'admin';
}else{
    protected $redirectTo = 'member';
}
```

**The avobe code is only for redirection. You can use middleware to protect admin panel from member.**